# Local.conf set up for devstack rocky

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, openstack, devstack, ceilometer

I want to use ceilometer with gnocchi database. 
I typed ceilimeter backbon = gnocchi
But when i use gnocchi CLI , it gives error
And also i can not use gnocchi API

Can you share local.conf which can set up gnocchi api successfully

Comment: Even I am experiencing the same problem with devstack! Were you able to find a solution for this?